# Как в конец определённой строки дописать нужную информацию

Tags: python

У меня есть файл, где построчно записаны данные.
У каждой строки есть свой порядковый номер, мне нужно в конец строки с определённым номером(с каждой итерацией он может быть разный, т.к. вводится пользователем) записывать определённую информацию (которая также вводится пользователем).
Был бы очень благодарен, если подсказали как это лучше всего реализовали.
Надеюсь, что более или менее понятно объяснил суть дела.

Comment: без насилования диска - никак, каждое изменение не в конце файла будет приводить к преезаписи всей последующей части до самого конца файла, т.е. если у вас в файле 1000 строк, и пользователь запишет данные в первую то будет перезаписан весь файл.

Comment: А что потом происходит с этой информацией? В смысле с файлом. Кроме дописывания в него данных для чего он нужен? Просто файл который Вы описали, претендует стать двумя таблицами БД

Answer (score 0):

Или считать файл в оперативку и записать целиком.

Или читать блоками и записывать в новый файл, потом удалить исходный и переименовать новый.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input())
text = input()
with open('infile.txt') as fi, open('outfile.txt') as fo:
    for i, line in enumerate(fi):
        fo.write(line)
        if i == n:
            fo.write(text)
        fo.write('\n')
```

Ну, может ещё надо `line = line.strip()` сделать, не помню, если будет лишний перевод строки получаться.

Comment: Благодарю, есть ещё вопрос, можно ли реализовать, чтобы он считывал с одного файла и после в него же записывал уже изменённый текст. Т.е. работа проходила без второго файла

Comment: Ну тогда сначала readlines() сделать, а потом по ним итерироваться